# Using WHERE twice in SELECT Statement

Tags: jquery, asp.net, select, where-clause

i have a search and

this is my code when the BUTTON is CLICKED to search

```
void GetProducts()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Products.ProductID, Products.Name, Categories.Category, " +
        "Products.Code, Products.Image, Products.Description, Products.Price, " +
        "Products.IsFeatured, Products.DateAdded, Products.DateModified, Products.Status, Products.Available, Products.Criticallevel " +
        "FROM Products INNER JOIN Categories ON Products.CatID = Categories.CatID WHERE Products.Available <= Products.Criticallevel";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Products");
    lvProducts.DataSource = ds;
    lvProducts.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}

void GetProducts1(string keyword)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Products.Available, Products.Criticallevel, Products.ProductID, Products.Name, Categories.Category, " +
        "Products.Code, Products.Image, Products.Description, Products.Price, " +
        "Products.IsFeatured, Products.DateAdded, Products.DateModified, Products.Status " +
        "FROM Products INNER JOIN Categories ON Products.CatID = Categories.CatID " +
        "WHERE Products.ProductID LIKE '%" + keyword + "%' OR Products.Name LIKE '%" + keyword + "%' " +
        " OR Categories.Category LIKE '%" + keyword + "%' OR Products.Code LIKE '%" + keyword + "%' " +
        " OR Products.Description LIKE '%" + keyword + "%' OR Products.Price LIKE '%" + keyword + "%' OR Available <= Criticallevel";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Products");
    lvProducts.DataSource = ds;
    lvProducts.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}

protected void btnSearch_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtSearch.Text.Trim() == "")
    {
        GetProducts();
    }
    else
    {
        GetProducts1(txtSearch.Text);
    }
}
```

when the page is viewed, WHERE does work.

But whenever i get to use the search and CLICK BUTTON,

where does not work.

SO HERE IS MY PAGE (just info)

[image]

it should show the same message `No Records Found` when i search 
because there are no products under WHERE.

But when Searched (btn clicked),

[image]

products shows.

please help guys!
thankyou in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have kept everything in OR condition which is wrong. Where conditon should be something like this
`WHERE Products.Available <= Products.Criticallevel AND (condition1 or condition2 or condition3)`

```
void GetProducts1(string keyword)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Products.Available, Products.Criticallevel, Products.ProductID, Products.Name, Categories.Category, " +
        "Products.Code, Products.Image, Products.Description, Products.Price, " +
        "Products.IsFeatured, Products.DateAdded, Products.DateModified, Products.Status " +
        "FROM Products INNER JOIN Categories ON Products.CatID = Categories.CatID " +
        "WHERE Available <= Criticallevel AND (Products.ProductID LIKE '%" + keyword + "%' OR Products.Name LIKE '%" + keyword + "%' " +
        " OR Categories.Category LIKE '%" + keyword + "%' OR Products.Code LIKE '%" + keyword + "%' " +
        " OR Products.Description LIKE '%" + keyword + "%' OR Products.Price LIKE '%" + keyword + "%')";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Products");
    lvProducts.DataSource = ds;
    lvProducts.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```